# Add shortcode to woocommerce product short description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a shortcode that will be placed on all single product posts. Specifically on the product's short description. I went to woocommerce templates and found a file "short-description" and I tried placed following code, but it's not working:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[wpqr-code]"); ?>
```

This shortcode is to supposed to generate and display a qr code on each product post where it is placed.

Comment: Please elaborate it more.... e.g. where this description is showing ? listing page or details page ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if anyone needs. Place this code in `functions.php`file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'enfold_customization_extra_product_content', 15 );
function enfold_customization_extra_product_content() {
    echo do_shortcode("[wpqr-code]");
}
```